# Google Sheets Filter Multi Column List With Another List Using A Function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange, google-sheets-filter, google-sheets-custom-function

I have two lists (A and B). I want to filter list "A" (a multi column list) with values in list "B" to create a Final List, list "C".

List "A" has multiple records for each student ID number. List "B" has a list of student ID numbers I want to include in list "C". I need all references to student ID Numbers in List "B" to appear in List "C" and I want all references to student ID numbers listed in list "A", but not in list "B" to be removed from List "C".

**List "A" Structure**

```
ID #    First   Last     Class
---     ---     ---      ---
123     Tim     Jones    Math
123     Tim     Jones    English
111     Amy     Smith    Science
111     Amy     Smith    GYM
222     Mike    Young    Math
222     Mike    Young    English
```

**List "B" Structure**

```
ID #    
---     
123     
222
```

**Desired List "C" Structure**

```
ID #    First   Last     Class
---     ---     ---      ---
123     Tim     Jones    Math
123     Tim     Jones    English
222     Mike    Young    Math
222     Mike    Young    English
```

I'm working with this formula, but I'm not sure how to structure the the part after this, `where Col1 =` nor am I positive it will work.

```
=query(importrange("1vutSseBMdVaivTbpX32rbXF4-7PNYImcAbsv6Q9Y-cE","data!A2:F"), " Select * where Col1 ='"&A2&"' ",1)
```

**I've also tried the below based on ttarchala answer, but it is only returning one row (ID#327288).**

=filter(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vutSseBMdVaivTbpX32rbXF4-7PNYImcAbsv6Q9Y-cE", "data!A2:2"), match(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vutSseBMdVaivTbpX32rbXF4-7PNYImcAbsv6Q9Y-cE", "data!A2:2"), IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vutSseBMdVaivTbpX32rbXF4-7PNYImcAbsv6Q9Y-cE", "myStudents!A2:A"), 0))

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a FILTER/MATCH combination. Example on your data below:

```
=filter(C52:F57; match(C52:C57; I53:I54; 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Hey @ttarchala! Thanks for offering help. I'm working  with your example and have written this formula, but it isn't working. Can you take a look and let me know if you can see what I'm missing?

`=filter(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vutSseBMdVaivTbpX32rbXF4-7PNYImcAbsv6Q9Y-cE", "data!A2:2"), match(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vutSseBMdVaivTbpX32rbXF4-7PNYImcAbsv6Q9Y-cE", "data!A2:2"), IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vutSseBMdVaivTbpX32rbXF4-7PNYImcAbsv6Q9Y-cE", "myStudents!A2:A"), 0))`

Comment: What error are you getting? I can't test your formula without permission to access your spreadsheet. If all else fails, put the results of importranges in separate sheets locally and filter from there.

Comment: =filter(data!A2:F, match(data!A2:A, myStudents!A2:A, 0)) @ttarchala, this worked. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

@ttarchala provided a very helpful answer. If you need to invert the selection you can simply do it like this:

```
=filter(C52:F57; ISNA (match(C52:C57; I53:I54; 0)))
```

Comment: Downvote was unnecessary, so upvote from me!